# C# SDL2.SDL_ttf.TTF_Init returning an error on the user's machine

Tags: c#, winforms, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

My project (executable file) works fine on my machine, but for some reason, on the user's machine program just can't start. Here is the error that I find in windows logs (sry it's on Russian but you can see that the problem is in missing dll) - [image]

But I am sure that the SDL_ttf library is in the project folder right next to the executable! [image]

So I can't really understand why the application is not working on the user's machine and works just fine on mine.

NOTE: I am using the binding if the SDL library from c++ written by flibitijibibo - https://github.com/flibitijibibo/SDL2-CS

Comment: SDL2_ttf depends on libfreetype (bundled with SDL2_ttf) and some version of CRT. You can check that with http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @keltar thank yow! I already solve the problem by adding libfreetype and zlib. Can u post your comment as an answer? I will confirm it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL2_ttf.dll, as many others, have some dependencies. E.g. if you download runtime package compiled with MSVC, you'll see `SDL2_ttf.dll`, `libfreetype-6.dll` and `zlib1.dll`. If you'll load it into [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) you'll see it also depends on `kernel32.dll`, `msvcrt.dll` (pre-installed on windows) and `SDL2.dll`, all of which have to be present on target system. Generally "DLL not found" means "DLL can't be loaded for whatever reason".